# Mandar pequisar mais de uma linha na mesma query

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Não consigo retornar os dados do banco quando tento fazer uma busca por mais produtos relacionados a categorias diferentes. Estou usando a seguinte *query*;

```
SELECT * FROM `app_product` WHERE app_category = 6 AND app_sub_category = 181
```

Nessa *query* eu obtenho todos os dados que estiverem na categoria **6** e subcategoria **181**. Até ai tudo certo, preciso de uma forma de busca numa única *query* mais dados por exemplo quero todos os dados que tenham a categoria **6** e subcategoria **181** e **182**  sem precisar criar uma *query* para cada condição deste jeito:

```
SELECT * FROM `app_product` WHERE app_category = 6 AND app_sub_category = 181
SELECT * FROM `app_product` WHERE app_category = 6 AND app_sub_category = 182
```

Existe alguma função do MySQL que eu possa usar nesse caso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da mesma forma que usou um `AND`, é só usar um `OR` quando quer um ou outro. Mas mais que aprender como faz isso minha sugestão é estudar lógica relacional.

```
SELECT * FROM `app_product` WHERE app_category = 6 AND (app_sub_category = 181 OR app_sub_category = 182)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/OneOrAnotherCode.sql).

Poderia usar o operador de `IN` como na outra resposta, mas para dois costuma ser mais comum algo assim, dependendo do banco de dados e versão pode ser mais performático fazer um ou outro.

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode utilizar o operador `IN` que é uma abreviação de várias condições `OR` em que você pode especificar vários valores em uma cláusula `WHERE`.

```
SELECT * FROM `app_product` WHERE app_category = 6 AND app_sub_category IN (181, 182);
```

Assim como pode fazer para retornar todas subcategorias, menos x, y, z...

```
SELECT * FROM `app_product` WHERE app_category = 6 AND app_sub_category NOT IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Nessa condição achei melhor pois e mais abreviada do que (app_sub_category = 181 OR app_sub_category = 182)